# How to properly assign json data into a javascript class?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have trouble to make functions inside for loop to run synchrosely

Inside EmployeePrint.js

```
fillData(item, taxObj) {
        let fullName = item.getFullName();
        let timePeriod = item.getTimePeriod();
        let grossIncome = item.getGrossIncome();
        let incomeTax = item.getIncomeTax(taxObj);
        let netIncome = item.getNetIncome();
        let mySuper = item.getSuper();

        this.name = fullName;
        this.payPeriod = timePeriod;
        this.grossIncome = grossIncome;
        this.incomeTax = incomeTax;
        this.netIncome = netIncome;
        this.mySuper = mySuper;

        return this;
    }
```

item is employee object. It has some methods and I run it inside fillData

```
async print(arr, fileName, taxObj) {
        let buf = [];

        arr.map(async (item) => {
            let ep = new EmployeePrint();
            ep = ep.fillData(item, taxObj);
            buf.push(ep);
        });

        return await this.printPromise(buf, fileName);
    }
```

After the fill data, I push employee object into array for printing later.

My issue is that I don't know how to make sure all funcs completed in each iteration.

Full project here: https://github.com/kenpeter/mb_new/tree/extend_base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you should call forEach and push into buf, or just use the returned value from map instead of even creating buf.

Second, you should use a for loop if you want to await inside a loop (not map or forEach) or simply map to promises and await all.

```
async print(arr, fileName, taxObj) {
  let buf = [];

  const promises = arr.map((item) => {
    let ep = new EmployeePrint();
    ep = ep.fillData(item, taxObj);
    buf.push(ep);
    return this.printPromise(buf, fileName);
  });
  await Promise.all(promises)
}
```